# Does Cnosdb support “create index”?

Tags: cnosdb

In IoT scenarios, many times we are unsure if a field in a table needs to be indexed. As the business evolves, we may realize the need for indexing. I noticed that in Cnosdb, all index fields are pre-built.Does Cnosdb support “create index”?